# MS Access Too Many fields during UPDATE

Tags: ms-access

When I try to UPDATE a table in MS Access, it gives and error saying too many fields defined. I googled and saw that i need to Repair and Compact, which I did, but still does not work?

Anyone has any ideas? Also, what actually count towards the "too many field" counter?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some info about how you perform the update? Using SQL?

Comment: Does the query include more than 255 fields?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The query was meant to run in a C# program I am writing. A foreach(hashtable) loop builds the query string. I stick a count++ in the loop and total no. of "fields=value" is 144. Copied the string to clipboard and paste in MS Access SQL design mode, the same error happens. Any idea?

Comment: Why not paste the string here?

Comment: @Remou hmmm.. ok pasted it here. there are only 140 "=" symbols. On another note, an INSERT with the same number of fields does not generate this error.

Comment: There are a few things that look a little odd for Access, for example `_HeaterFlangeBoltingType=''`, because zero length strings are usually a problem also, `_CorrosionAllowance='3'` because this looks like it should be a numeric value, that is, no quotes, also `_ModifiedDate='30/12/2010 4:50:50 PM'` because the delimiter for dates is #, not quote.

Comment: Wouldn't blank values want to be illustrated in such a query as NULL?  For example - _MolecularWeight=NULL instead of _MolecularWeight=''?

Comment: @Comrad_Durandal It is possible to set up Access to accept zero-length strings, however, I agree that it is unusual, as I mentioned in an earlier comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I seem to have found the answer:

> The Microsoft Jet database engine has
>   an internal limit of 255 fields per
>   query. As the Microsoft Jet database
>   engine iterates through the records in
>   an update query, it creates a field
>   for the original value and a field for
>   the updated value. When more than 127
>   fields are selected, it reaches the
>   255 field limit of a query.
>
> Consider the following SQL for an
>   update query: UPDATE Table SET A=B,
>   C=D Internally the query looks as
>   follows: SELECT A,B,C,D FROM Table

-- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199076

You have ~140 fields, do you not?

Comment: Wow. I did not know that at all. Of course, I have a hard time conceiving of where I'd need to do this, as I don't have any tables with that many fields in them to begin with. Also, whenever I need to coordinate data between two versions of a table, I do a bunch of column-by-column updates, instead of a single row-to-row update. That's likely why I'd never encounter this problem, since my resulting generated SQL is updating only 1 column at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried splitting the UPDATE query up across perhaps a few?  Perhaps chunk it out to two or three - verifying each took before proceeding with the next?  Could help toward your 'Too many fields' problem, and allow you to debug problems easier?  Just a thought, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks Comrad, that's exactly what I am doing now. But what I need now is more of an explanation of how this is happening. Because clearly, I only have 140 (less than 255) fields.

Comment: @Jake I suspect this may be a misleading error, hence my comment above. Have you considered data types?

Comment: @Remou yes i have taken the data types into consideration. actually everything is text except _LN, _REV and the Date fields. For the date time fields, seems like it does automatic type conversion so it still works.

Comment: Also, if I split into 2 UPDATEs it works separately. So I don't think the delimiters make much difference?