# Amount of Columns allowed in Access VBA Update Query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to update all rows of a table after importing data from excel to access with this code:

```
enter code here
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE ([tbl1] INNER JOIN [2] ON " _ 
                & "[tbl1].[Nr]= [tbl2].[Nr]) " _
                & "INNER JOIN [tblExcelImport] " _
                & "ON [tbl1].[Nr] = [tblExcelImport].[Nr] " _
                & "SET " & strSQL & " " _
                & "WHERE [tblExcelImport].[Type]= 'TYPE1';"
```

strSQL contains following string:
"[tbl1].[ColumnA]= [tblExcelImport]![ColumnA], [tbl1].[ColumnB]= [tblExcelImport]![ColumnB]" ... and much more columns.

So my question is how many columns can I put in to strSQL inside of a UPDATE query 
in access VBA? I tried it with different amount of columns but I could not really conclude a strict logic in that.

Comment: As you can only have 256 (or is it 255?) columns in a table in access - I would guess that's the limit to the update query.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth yes

Answer (score 0):

next time I'll do more research in here I promise :D
Solved in the link:
[MS Access Too Many fields during UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561613/ms-access-too-many-fields-during-update)